# Como verificar se um sevidor está no .ssh/known_hosts?

Tags: shell, bash, shell-script

Tenho um script que sincroniza repositórios git. Caso o repositório nunca tenha sido sincronizado, os diretórios são criados.

Eventualmente, quando um repositório é adicionado, o servidor em que serve o repositório não está listado no arquivo `.ssh/known_hosts` e o cliente ssh não prossegue pois é necessário confirmar a inclusão da chave pública no arquivo.

Como faço para verificar se o servidor já está listado no `.ssh/known_hosts`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta executar o comando `ssh-keygen -H -F <hostname>`. O comando retorna a linha em que o hostname está incluído, ou não retorna nada caso não encontrar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode executar antes:

```
awk '{print $1}' .ssh/known_hosts
```

E ver quais são os hosts conhecidos.

Comment: teu código falta o path completo para o comando funcionar a contento, a menos que esteja no próprio diretório. Talvez o correto seria: 
awk '{print $1}' ~/.ssh/known_hosts